# Symfony 413 Request Entity Too Large File

Tags: forms, symfony, upload, large-files

I am trying to upload a file with ajax and when the file is to large I get the error page as html 413 file too large.

I don't want to change the php settings to allow larger files, I don't need that.

I need to catch this error in my controller and instead of the error I want to output an json response with a message.

I am using dropzone to allow me to upload multiple files with dropdown functionality.

Does anyone know how to catch the default exception from symfony ?
Thanks

Comment: Is the error comes from Symfony (I don't think so)? If you want catch a error with Symfony controller, then you should upload file via Symfony controller.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a framework issue, webservers is stopping execution of the request when browser tries to submit a file large enough to exceed the limit.

If you are using Apache as a webserver take a look at [Custom Error Responses](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html). You can configure apache to execute your script when some errors happens. In this script you can check if request done via ajax or not and return corresponding content (json or text/html)